# What are the mechanisms for code reuse in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Trying to understand the mechanisms of code reuse in Elixir and when they are applicable. For example, we have inheritance, mixins, and metaprogramming (helps reduce boilerplate) in Ruby.

Comment: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html that covers a lot of it.

Comment: You may want to read inside this book https://books.google.it/books?id=_SigDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA225&ots=pI2vuyD15m&dq=code%20reuse%20in%20elixir&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Elixir macros allow you to generate code at compile time.

The `use` keyword invokes the `__using__` macro in the module given.

For example `use GenServer` defines all the required callbacks for a module that will implement the gen_server behaviour.

Macros are generally only required when building a framework. Regular application code can usually be made of modules and functions.

Comment: You can also import function from other mudules using the `import` statement.